# Choosing ALU functions

Tags: alu

*I am currently taking the [Nand2Tetris](http://www.nand2tetris.org/) course online, where I am in the process of building a virtual computer all from nand gates. I have learned what an ALU is, how it works, and build a simple virtual one myself.*

Now I would like to make my own physical 8 bit ALU from simple 74(HC) series IC's. I have experience in building electronics and using the IC's, on a hobby level. My only real problem is that I don't know which functions to choose for my new ALU. In the virtual ALU I build there are input x and y, and 6 functions: 
- zero x
- not x (bitwise), 
- zero y, 
- not y (bitwise), 
- f (0: x AND y 1: x + y), 
- not(bitwise, on everything).

I am going to build a whole whole computer, so i could of course just for example add multiplication with software later, but I would probably like to have more hardware functions. From my research i found out about in- and decrementers, left/right shifting, other "full" multiplying/dividing circuits and of course more logical implementations. **But i have no idea what functions are needed/useful to have in an ALU, and what is a good balance between hardware and software implementations.**

Comment: I would not go and start building your project in actual Hardware for a first step. If you are interested in learning, you can enhance your learning rate by using an off-the-shelf FPGA board over a discrete implementation. You can learn VHDL, build your own ALU in emulated Hardware (Drag and drop your 74HCs instead of soldering), can revise and extend this ALU by software updates, an still have a physical board you can connect push buttons and LEDs too for visual testing and prove of concept. You wont need any custom PCBs, so soldering required and so on.

Comment: Far as functions of two variables *x* and *y* go, I remember *zero*, *not x*, *not y*, *x AND y* and *x + y*. Consider explicating in your question: What is *zero x*? What is *not(bitwise, on everything)*? You seem to be undecided on *instruction set* rather than ALU functions&implementation. It is good development practice to have implementation follow specification and design: implement your *simple virtual ALU*. Make changes to the virtual one, first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i have no idea what functions are needed/useful to have in an ALU

Neither do we as you didn't specify the application that your ALU should be used in. What is a **use**ful function of a device depends on its **use**.

The [wikipedia article has a nice list of common functionality, i.e.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit)

1. add
2. add with carry
3. subtract
4. and
5. or
6. shift

[It also makes a statement on more complex functionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit#Complex_operations):

> Although an ALU can be designed to perform complex functions, the resulting higher circuit complexity, cost, power consumption and larger size makes this impractical in many cases. Consequently, ALUs are often limited to simple functions

I think that makes sense and agree.

One example for more complex functionality could be a [MAC-unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation)
Which can be capable of doing a multiplication of two numbers in one cycle, which is useful for some real time applications.

As you can see this is basically a simple arithmetic operation, yet it is not included in the ALU but a dedicated unit.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll keep it simple and look at the article then. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: one's and two's complements are also useful functions. Though if you have XOR and Subtract, you can do both anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to look at is what functions were provided in various MSI (medium scale integration) ALU IC's that appeared some 40 years ago, when high end CPUs were still being built from discrete chips.  Both of the chips below were bit-slice 4-bit ALU's, so four of them would be needed on a 16-bit computer, and eight for a 32-bit computer.

Here is a 48 function table from the [74F181](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/74F181.pdf) using four select lines (16) plus two extra control leads:

[image]

which perhaps goes a little overboard.  However it was a very popular chip, and was used in many mini-computers like the PDP-11 and VAX 11/780.

Here is a simpler 8-function table from the [74F381](https://www.engineering.uiowa.edu/sites/default/files/ees/files/NI/pdfs/00/95/DS009528.pdf), that uses just three select lines:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Relax, you need an ALU, but not to do everything. Only enough to lookup the rest in tables. Rotations for example, do I need ALU rotation to lookup rotation? No, so just table those in ROM. Same for multiplication, division, remainder. IBM abused this cheat for the 1620 CADET (Can't Add Doesn't Even Try).

Start with 4way MUX. Let A vs B choose an input. Feed those four inputs with a Karnaugh map to define the logic output.

Most 4way MUX include a twin. 74HC253 for you perhaps? Sharing same A vs B, select EQ LT GT EQ to compare magnitude and produce EQn+1. Chain to the next pair of EQ inputs.

A<B comparison reveals all of A-B's positive logic borrows. Only need a real XOR gate to combine a mapped XOR with the prior EQn+1 to make full subtraction. Compare A>B for B-A instead. Addition by XORverted B maybe wants another gate...

You can eliminate combinatorial ripple by upgrade to 74CBT3253. Same pinout as 74HC253 but surface mount. Transmission gates solve the chain by series current that flows through, or not...

Set LT EQo GT controls low to disable the chain for pure logic.

CRUMB sim doesn't offer 74HC253 or CBT3253 yet. Made do with HC157's.
[image: CRUMMYALU]

Comment: How do *rotations, multiplication, division, remainder* come up? Does this answer the implied *How do I chose ALU functions for a 7400-series implementable ALU when building a whole home-brew computer?*

Comment: Breadboard diagrams are not useful please use a schematic